# Converting TimeSpan to "hh:mm" higher than 23:59

Tags: c#, format, timespan

im Capturing Worktime in a Timespan.

If the Timespan has a Span higher than 23:59 my convert to a hh:mm format will only do 23:59, after that it starts at 01:00 again.

I want to be able to Display 24:05 Hours
My Conversion to a Decimal (24.08 Hours) works fine.

Any Suggestions where i go wrong? have been comparing string format since 2 Days, and i think i do smth fundamentally wrong

decimal:

> string decimalHours = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value.Dauer).TotalHours.ToString("0.00");

hh:mm :

> string hhmmHours = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value.Dauer).ToString(@"hh:mm");

Edit: For Clarification changed the times (dumb way to show things from me )

Comment: "...I want to be able to Display **24:05** Hours My Conversion to a Decimal (**23,5 Hours**) works fine." 24.05 hours is not equal to a decimal of 23.5!? One of them is wrong in the explanation. Nevertheless, interesting question. Let me setup a sample project to work it out. Brb.

Comment: That's how `TimeSpan.ToString()` is builded ... where is the problem to use `(int)TotalHours`

Comment: @BernoulliIT Sorry this maybe was badly typed. The 24:05 had nothing to do with 23.5, there were just 2 random examples :P

1:30 = 1,5 :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to format a `TimeSpan` object via `.ToString(format)` overload the way you'd like.

Look at [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings), **hh** format cannot exceed **23** :

> **hh**    The number of hours, which ranges from "00" to "23".

You will have to build the format you want using **.TotalHours**.

What about:

```cs
var ts = new TimeSpan(hours: 50, minutes: 10, seconds: 20);
var hours = Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours);
var formatted = $"{hours}:{ts.Minutes}:{ts.Seconds}";
Console.WriteLine(formatted); // Display 50:10:20
```

You could even create an extension method.

Comment: Thanks ! An Extension Method wont be needed, but this will hit my Private Lib. 
btw. It works like a chaaaaaarm

Comment: @nico-walsemann you should consider setting one of the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

@dbraillon is right. And this is just a simple solution to achieve want you desire:

```
TimeSpan timeWorked = new(1, 0, 30, 0);

$"{Math.Floor(timeWorked.TotalHours)}:{timeWorked.Minutes}";
```

Round the total number of hours to the nearest integer towards zero with `Math.Floor` and take the minutes component of the TimeSpan for the number of minutes (no need to do any conversion on minutes).